# Dealing with Memcached Race Conditions

Tags: ruby, key, memcached, race-condition

I have two different sources of data which I need to marry together. Data set A will have a foo_key attribute which can map to Data set B's bar_key attribute with a one to many relationship.

Data set A:

`[{ foo_key: 12345, other: 'blahblah' }, ...]`

Data set B:

`[{ bar_key: 12345, other: '' }, { bar_key: 12345, other: '' }, { bar_key: 12345, other: '' }, ...]`

Data set A is coming from a SQS queue and any relationships with data set B will be available as I poll A.

Data set B is coming from a separate SQS queue that I am trying to dump into a memcached cache to do quick look ups on when an object drops into data set A.

Originally I was planning on setting the memcached key to be bar_key from the objects in data set B but then realized that if I did that it would be possible to overwrite the value since there can be many of the same bar_key value. Then I was thinking well I can create a key bar_key and the value just be an array of the SQS messages. But since I have multiple hosts polling the SQS queue I think it might be possible that when I check to see if the key is in memcached, check it out, append the new message to it, and then set it, that another host could be trying to preform the same operation and thus the first host's attempt at appending the value would just be overwritten.

I've looked around at memcached key locking but I'm not sure I understand it entirely. Would the solution be that when I get the key/value pair from memcached I create a temporary dummy lock on a new key called bar_key_dummy that expires in x seconds, and if I try to fetch a key that has a bar_key_dummy lock active I just send the SQS message back to the queue without deleting to try again in x seconds?

Here's some pseudocode for what I have going on in my head. Does this make any sense?

```
store = MemCache.new(host)

sqs_messages.poll do |message|
  dummy_key = "#{message.bar_key}_dummy"
  sqs.dont_delete_message && next unless store.get(dummy_key).nil?
  # set dummy_key in memcache with a value of 1 for 3 seconds
  store.set(dummy_key, 1, 3)
  temp_data = store.get(message.bar_key) || []
  temp_data << message
  store.set(message.bar_key, temp_data, 300)
  # delete dummy key when done in case shorter than x seconds
  store.delete(dummy_key)
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Memcached has a special operation - `cas` Compare and Swap.

Command `gets` returns Item along with its unique CAS value.
Then dataset can be searched and update must be issued with the `cas` command which takes original unique CAS value.

If CAS was changed in between two command, update operation will fail with the `EXISTS` error